# crawling website that needs authentication

Tags: web-crawler

How would I write a simple script (in cURL/python/ruby/bash/perl/java) that logs in to [okcupid](http://okcupid.com) and tallies how many messages I've received each day?

The output will be something like:

```
1/21/2011    1 messages
1/22/2011    0 messages
1/23/2011    2 messages
1/24/2011    1 messages
```

The main issue is that I have never written a web crawler before. I have no idea how to programmatically log in to a site like okcupid. How do you make the authentication persist while loading different pages? etc..

Once I get access to the raw HTML, I'll be okay via regex and maps etc.

Comment: Way to harness the power of nerd to find love. Kudos =)

Comment: sounds like you need to learn cURL..

Comment: @George: Thanks!, @Brynjar: cURL would be fine too, though I've never used it. Could you post some details?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using cURL that downloads the first page of the inbox. A proper solution will iterate the last step for each page of messages. `$USERNAME` and `$PASSWORD` need to be filled in with your info.

```
#!/bin/sh

## Initialize the cookie-jar
curl --cookie-jar cjar --output /dev/null https://www.okcupid.com/login

## Login and save the resulting HTML file as loginResult.html (for debugging purposes)
curl --cookie cjar --cookie-jar cjar \
  --data 'dest=/?' \
  --data 'username=$USERNAME' \
  --data 'password=$PASSWORD' \
  --location \
  --output loginResult.html \
    https://www.okcupid.com/login

## Download the inbox and save it as inbox.html
curl --cookie cjar \
  --output inbox.html \
  http://www.okcupid.com/messages
```

This technique explained in a [video tutorial about cURL](http://www.linuxjournal.com/video/use-curl-login-websites-script).