# Programmatically login to OKC

Tags: python, urllib2

I'm trying to programatically login to OKCupid ([www.okcupid.com/login](http://www.okcupid.com/login))in order to fetch scrape some user data.  I've tried to put together a python script to do this, but seem to be doing something wrong.

The behavior I'd like from this sample script is to login, follow a redirect to the homepage  then print the HTML response.  Here's what I have so far:

```
import urllib, urllib2, cookielib

# cookie storage
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(
    urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj),
    urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler
    )
# Useragent
opener.addheaders.append(('User-agent','Mozilla/4.0'))

url = 'http://www.okcupid.com/login'
login_data = urllib.urlencode({
    'username':'myusername',
    'password':'mypassword',
    })

req = urllib2.Request(url,login_data)
resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = resp.read()

print the_page
```

Comment: Why the down vote?  This is a legitimate question surrounding getting a corpus of data for text analysis.

Comment: Are you sure that's the right data to be passing in as user and pass?

Comment: Those are placeholders for my username and password.

Comment: Meant `username` and `user_pass` . Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787196/crawling-website-that-needs-authentication. Maybe that's what you need; 'username' and 'password' instead.

Comment: It was supposed to be username, thanks for the catch.  I get the same page printout though.

Comment: I've been fooling around with `requests` and I even tried checking out the responses sent to and from okcupid within a browser, but I couldn't figure it out. Dunno much about this sort of thing though. Good luck!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14228/discussion-between-tankorsmash-and-sevenless)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the error. I built the opener, then didn't use it.  Here's the fix:

```
import urllib, urllib2, cookielib

# cookie storage
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(
    urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj),
    urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler
    )
# Useragent
opener.addheaders.append(('User-agent','Mozilla/4.0'))

url = 'http://www.okcupid.com/login'
login_data = urllib.urlencode({
    'username':'myusername',
    'password':'mypassword',
    })

req = urllib2.Request(url,login_data)
resp = opener.open(req)
the_page = resp.read()

print the_page
```

Comment: it would be much easier to use the requests library

Answer (score 1):

based on what you are doing, here's an example of what i'm doing to login, then go to messages and save all usernames

```
import urllib, urllib2, cookielib
import re
# cookie storage
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(
    urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj),
    urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler
    )
# Useragent
opener.addheaders.append(('User-agent','Mozilla/4.0'))


url = 'http://www.okcupid.com/login'
login_data = urllib.urlencode({
    'username':'Mobius1',
    'password':'raptor22',
    })

urllib2.install_opener(opener)

res = opener.open(url, login_data)

print res.url #should be http://www.okcupid.com/home if successful
res.close()

#navigate profile after successful login
res = opener.open('http://www.okcupid.com/messages')
the_page = res.read() #read content at URL

#find all usernames from page content with pattern /profile/username?
UserNameList = re.findall(r'/profile/([\w\.-]+)?', the_page)
print UserNameList

with open('OkC_messages.html', 'w') as fid: #save the_page as html
    fid.write(the_page)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://github.com/IvanMalison/okcupyd. It does exactly what you need to do and it provides some nice abstractions.